# SQL BETWEEN Statement is returning only match results

Tags: sql, oracle, between

I am using SQL Oracle DB, I am facing issue when using SQL Between Statement.
I have a requirement to search the values in between the date time range.
When I am using the below SQL statement, I am only receiving matching results or empty set but I need the results which are between the values inclusive the passing values if present.

```
select id,date 
from Table_name 
where date between '2020-10-21 10:00:17' AND '2017-10-21 22:00:17' 
  and id = '123';
```

I am receiving as Empty set

Example of output should be

```
ID       DATE
123    2020-10-21 10:00:17
123    2020-09-07 09:87:22
123    2018-06-09 07:58:01
123    2017-08-12 08:00:10
```

Could anyone suggest what should be modified in the sql statement

Comment: As a general rule, [avoid `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) when dates and times are involved.

Comment: @JeroenMostert , could you suggest me other than BETWEEN, what can I use for this statement then.
I need dates passing should be returned if it is matched with DB result and also the dates which fall between the values

Comment: My bad, the article I linked specifically applies to SQL Server, not Oracle. A lot of what's in there is not applicable to Oracle because it doesn't have the same rounding issues, except the general observation that explicitly using `>=` and `<` prevents the boundary issues you get with `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to swap the two date values after between in your SQL statement.

Explanation: between in this statement means:

```
date >= '2020-10-21 10:00:17' and date <= '2017-10-21 22:00:17'
```

The correct statement is:

```
select id, date
  from Table_name
 where date between '2017-10-21 22:00:17' and '2020-10-21 10:00:17'
   and id = '123';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. You want the lower bound of the range before the upper bound in the `BETWEEN` clause; and
2. You are not comparing on a date-time range, you are comparing on an alpha-numeric string comparison. This is because the values in the `BETWEEN` clause are string literals and not `DATE` values.

You want to use `DATE` values in the `BETWEEN` clause:

```sql
select id,
       date_column
from   Table_name
where  date_column BETWEEN DATE '2017-10-21' + INTERVAL '22:00:17' HOUR TO SECOND
                       AND DATE '2020-10-21' + INTERVAL '10:00:17' HOUR TO SECOND
and    id = '123';
```

or

```sql
select id,
       date_column
from   Table_name
where  date_column BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2017-10-21 22:00:17'
                       AND TIMESTAMP '2020-10-21 10:00:17'
and    id = '123';
```

or

```sql
select id,
       date_column
from   Table_name
where  date_column BETWEEN TO_DATE('2017-10-21 22:00:17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                       AND TO_DATE('2020-10-21 10:00:17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
and    id = '123';
```

---

If you use string literals and the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter does not match then you will get an error:

```sql
select id,
       date_column
from   Table_name
where  date_column between '2017-10-21 22:00:17' and '2020-10-21 10:00:17'
and    id = '123';
```

Outputs:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c9fae1b1ea13fd2176bade34c5bc56a4)*